# Javascript: how to sort elements of a class

Tags: javascript

I have a blog which produces a list like this on a php/html page

```
<div id="unique-id-4" class="blog-entry">Bert blah blah</div>
<div id="unique-id-2" class="blog-entry">Andy blah blah</div>
<div id="unique-id-3" class="blog-entry">Chas blah blah</div>
<div id="unique-id-1" class="blog-entry">Dave blah blah</div>
```

I want to reorder the divs on the page using javascript.

**Firstly**, to see how it works, an **alphabetical sort**. (That may be enough for this question).
But **secondly** (what I really want to do) **sort them by "age"**. I have an array of each person's name and age which I can reference. Is this even possible?

I found this when looking for finding by class

`var content = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-entry')`

The sorted output could be on the same page, or on a different page - it doesn't matter. thanks for any help. I know very little about javascript.

I'd like to sort in the order 
1) Andy, Bert, Chas, Dave (i.e. "alphabetically) producing:

```
<div id="unique-id-2" class="blog-entry">Andy blah blah</div>
<div id="unique-id-4" class="blog-entry">Bert blah blah</div>
<div id="unique-id-3" class="blog-entry">Chas blah blah</div>
<div id="unique-id-1" class="blog-entry">Dave blah blah</div>
```

and ideally

2) By their ages, where in a separate array: Andy = 42, Bert =18, Chas = 73, Dave = 56; producing

```
<div id="unique-id-4" class="blog-entry">Bert blah blah</div>
<div id="unique-id-2" class="blog-entry">Andy blah blah</div>
<div id="unique-id-1" class="blog-entry">Dave blah blah</div>
<div id="unique-id-3" class="blog-entry">Chas blah blah</div>
```

Comment: See this working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myk2X/3/).

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not entirely sure what you intend to sort by this should cover all angles.

```
/*Sort my entries
  sortProperty = DOM object property that is to be used to sort in ascending order
*/
function sortMyEntries(sortProperty)
{
    var blogEntries = document.getElementsByClassName("blog-entry");
    blogEntries = Array.prototype.slice.call(blogEntries,0)
    blogEntries.sort(function(a,b)
         {
             return (a[sortProperty] > b[sortProperty]);
         })
    return blogEntries;
}
```

This method is currently limited to dealing with a question specific selector but it is fairly flexible.  For example both of the following are applicable

```
sortMyEntries("id");  //Sort blog entries by DOM object id
sortMyEntries("innerHTML");  //Sort blog entries by DOM object innerHTML
```

Comment: Note that using `Array.prototype.slice.call` on a non-array in IE8 and lower fails.

Answer (score 3):

Using no magic or unsupport methods:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var filtered = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].className === "blog-entry") {
       filtered.push(elements[i]);
    }  
}
var sorted = filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
   return a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML; 
});

var parent = elements[0].parentNode;

for (i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    parent.appendChild(sorted[i]);
}
```

[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ad7GV/1)

[Node information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node)

---

For an array based sort:

```
var people = [{name: "Andy", age: 20}, {name: "Bob", age: 67}];

var sorted = filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
   return people[a.innerHTML].age > people[b.innerHTML].age; 
});
```

Comment: `childNodes.length = 0` works as a way of removing all children?

Comment: It doesn't. I meant to remove it.

Comment: Yeah, but there's not enough information to really solve that problem. I could write an example, but it might not fit his needs.

Comment: This looks like it has potential… Thanks! I've got a lot to work in all these examples to see what I can adapt.

Answer (score 2):

1. `var content = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-entry')` will give you node list of `HTMLElement` object in content.
2. Convert it to `Array`.
3. Sort it using the [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.
4. On the callback, compare the objects using their `innerHTML` property.

http://jsfiddle.net/myk2X/3/ is a working example. The silver container holds the initial objects, and the light green container holds the result.

Comment: You will need to include a step to convert the content result into an array in order to use the sort function such as Array.prototype.slice.call(content,0);

Comment: content is not an array, its a live nodelist

Comment: We can make an array using `array.push()`

Comment: @Raynos See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myk2X/3/). I created an array from live node list. then sorted it.

Comment: I've looked at your example and it seems to work perfectly for the alphabetical example. Many thanks - I will now try to understand it …

Answer (score 2):

First thing, `content` is not an array here. It is NodeList. So the steps to do.

1. Convert NodeList to array
2. Sort array
3. Remove all blog entries
4. Add from sorted array

   ```
   <div id="blogs">
    <div id="unique-id-4" class="blog-entry">Bert blah blah</div>
    <div id="unique-id-2" class="blog-entry">Andy blah blah</div>
    <div id="unique-id-3" class="blog-entry">Chas blah blah</div>
    <div id="unique-id-1" class="blog-entry">Dave blah blah</div>
   </div>


   var blogs = document.getElementById("blogs");
   var blogEntries = blogs.getElementsByClassName('blog-entry');
   blogEntries = Array.prototype.slice.call(blogEntries);
   if(blogEntries && blogEntries.length){
     blogEntries.sort(sortBlogs);
     while (blogs.hasChildNodes()) {
        blogs.removeChild(blogs.lastChild);
     }
     while(blogEntries.length){
        var blogEntry = blogEntries.shift();
        blogs.appendChild(blogEntry);
     }
   }

   function sortBlogs(a, b){
     var aid = parseInt(a.id.replace("unique-id-", ""));
     var bid = parseInt(b.id.replace("unique-id-", ""));
     return aid - bid;  
   }
   ```

See a demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/8W6AU/7/
Modify the function `sortBlogs` for the sorting needed. Now it uses id for sorting.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it reverse sorts the unique-id. I will certainly study the code to see what terms I can use.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how your arrays are stored (does `unique-id-X` correspond to `ages[X]`?) but here's the general method: pass a custom comparison function to [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
function toArray(obj) {
    var r = [], i = 0, l = obj.length;

    for(; i < l; i++) {
        if(i in obj) {
            r[i] = obj[i];
        }
    }

    return r;
}

var elements = toArray(document.getElementsByClassName('blog-entry')); // Doesn't have full browser support, so you might want to use jQuery, e.g. here.
var ages = [...];
var names = [...];

elements.sort(function(element1, element2) {
    var index1 = elements.indexOf(element1); 
    var index2 = elements.indexOf(element2);

    // Sort by name first:
    if(names[index1] < names[index2]) { // Can do case-insensitive comparison here, too.
        return -1;
    } else if(names[index1] > names[index2]) {
        return 1;
    } else if(ages[index1] < ages[index2]) {
        // Names were equal, sort by age.
        return -1;
    } else if(ages[index1] > ages[index2]) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        // They're equal.
        return 0;
    }
}).forEach(function(element) {
    // This is where the magic happens! appendChild() is just called in order.
    // The best part is that it looks like it does almost nothing.
    element.parentNode.appendChild(element);
});
```

Of course, there are two **things that might not work in IE.** (Happy, Raynos?) One is `document.getElementsByClassName`, and the other is `Array.forEach`. Those aren't supported in some browsers, i.e. IE. Here's a compatibility script for `Array.forEach`:

```
if(![].forEach) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function(action, thisArg) {
        for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
            if(i in this) {
                action.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName is _not_ a non-standard extension, nor is `Array#forEach`

Comment: @Raynos: Sorry, I meant "incompatible" :P

Comment: also getElementsByClassName is from DOM4, not from ES5

Comment: sorry, I think I may have confused things with the unique-ids. Those are not the ages - but I included them because each blog div has one and they're *not* in the order that I want to use. So the sorting has to happen elsewhere.  The ages are in a separate array (I've now edited the original post). So it's like you have 2 arrays, A with the divs for Andy Bert etc and B with pairs of data Andy, 42: Bert, 18; etc. And you use the hi-low order of ages in B to order the divs in A.

Comment: This solution seems to take on board the age array - so will be useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the ideal opportunity to use jQuery and a plugin along the lines of [TinySort](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/TinySort).

Comment: WTH? Why why down-vote? I'm pretty sure jQuery + an extension like TinySort should address this problem. Please provide a reason for the down-vote next time...

Comment: Maybe OP didn't tag this question with *jQuery*

Comment: Including jQuery is a waste of space, completely overkill. Using some third party plugin with questionable code quality is even worse.